# Django send an email on post_save with templates

Tags: html, django, vue.js, sendmail

I'm attempting to send an email our admin when new data is submitted to our website from the users. We are using a Django for the backend and Vue for the front end, even though that probably doesn't matter. Here is the code:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def send_update(sender, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        data=kwargs['instance']
        try:
            if data.admin_approved == False:
                print("point 1 reached")
                name = data.submitted_by_name
                body = data.body
                content_type = str(sender).split(".")[2][:-2]
                print("point 2 reached")
                link = "https://link_to_website.com" + content_type.lower()
                subject = "New " + content_type + " submitted"
                print("point 3 reached")
                from_email = "NoReply@web_site.com"
                to_email = "my_email@address.com"
                print("pre-html point reached")
                html_message = get_template('./email/template.html')
                text_message = get_template('./email/textplate.txt')
                data = {
                        'user_name': name,
                        'submission': data.body,
                        'type': content_type,
                        'link': link,
                        'body': body
                    }
                content_text = text_message.render(data)
                content_html = html_message.render(data)
                print("ready to send email!")
                msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, content_text, from_email, [to_email])
                msg.attach_alternative(content_html, "text/html")
                msg.send()
        except:
            print("Data was not submitted by an non-admin user.")
```

The try/except is included so that data that is submitted directly through the django admin page does not trigger the email function.

the function works up until "pre-html point reached", I'm guessing the issue is somewhere within the msg and msg.send() but I am not receiving any error functions.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're not receiving any error messages *because you explicitly hide them with that blank except*. Never, ever do that; remove that try/except completely and let Django tell you what is wrong. If an exception is raised when Django sends an email from the admin, then *catch that exception only*, but even better, find out why it is being raised and prevent it in the first place.

Comment: Welp, I am an idiot. Thanks a lot